how to accept multiple client input and display it using socket c
I am trying to make a simple CLI messaging in C . I found out about sockets .
I have wrote a simple program where client can write some message and server prints it in server side
I tried opening multiple clients and it only accepted one client,
I wanna make a program where many clients can join up server instead of one and write some messages , currently only server prints client messages in server side but when other clients join
and send message
I want  clients to be able to see other client messages
Currently i have
server.c
/*
server.c
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define MAX 256
#define PORT 8080

int main() {
    int socket_return, accept_return, bind_return, listen_return;
    struct sockaddr_in server_address, peer_address;

    // Creating  socket
    socket_return = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (socket_return == -1) {
        perror("socket creation failed\n");
        return -1;
    } else {
        printf("socket created\n");
    }
    //empty the server address`
    bzero(&server_address, sizeof(server_address));

    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    server_address.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    // binding socket
    bind_return = bind(socket_return, (struct sockaddr *)&server_address, sizeof(server_address));
    if (bind_return == -1) {
        perror("binding failed\n");
        close(socket_return);
        return -1;
    } else {
        printf("binding done\n");
    }

    // listening the socket
    listen_return = listen(socket_return, 5);
    if (listen_return == -1) {
        perror("listening failed");
        close(socket_return);
        return -1;
    } else {
        printf("server is  listening...\n");
    }

    socklen_t peer_address_len = sizeof(peer_address);
    // accept connection
    accept_return = accept(socket_return, (struct sockaddr *)&peer_address, &peer_address_len);
    if (accept_return == -1) {
        perror("accepting failed\n");
        close(socket_return);
        return -1;
    } else {
        printf("connection accepted\n");
    }
    char msg[MAX];
    while (1) {
        bzero(msg, sizeof(msg));

        // Read message
        ssize_t bytes_read = read(accept_return, msg, sizeof(msg) );
        if (bytes_read == 0) {
            printf("client disconnected\n");
            break;
        } else if (bytes_read < 0) {
            perror("failed to read message\n");
            break;
        }
        //displaying client message
        printf("From client: %s", msg);

    }

    // closing
    close(accept_return);
    close(socket_return);

    return 0;
}


client.c
/*
client.c
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define MAX 256
#define PORT 8080

int main() {
    int socket_return, connect_return;
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;

    // Creating  socket
    socket_return = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (socket_return == -1) {
        printf("socket creation failed\n");
        return -1;
    } else {
        printf("socket created\n");
    }

    bzero(&server_address, sizeof(server_address));

    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    server_address.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    // Connecting the server
    connect_return = connect(socket_return, (struct sockaddr *)&server_address, sizeof(server_address));
    if (connect_return == -1) {
        printf("connection failed\n");
        close(socket_return);
        return -1;
    } else {
        printf("connected to server\n");
    }

    char msg[MAX];
    int i;

    while (1) {
        bzero(msg, sizeof(msg));
        printf("Enter string: ");
        i = 0;
        while ((msg[i++] = getchar()) != '\n');
        //when server detects the client message as 'exit' close the server
        if ((strncmp(msg, "exit", 4)) == 0) {
            printf("Exiting client\n");
            close(socket_return);
            break;
        }
        // sending message
        write(socket_return, msg, sizeof(msg));
        printf("You wrote %s\n",msg);
    }

    // close
    close(socket_return);

    return 0;
}




I tried opening multiple clients and it only accepted one client

Well yes.  Your server performs only one accept() call per run, so it will accept at most one client.  What's more, it then devotes its full attention to receiving and displaying data from that one client, and when that client disconnects or an attempt to read fails, the server terminates.

I wanna make a program where many clients can join up server instead of one and write some messages , currently only server prints client messages in server side but when other clients join and send message I want clients to be able to see other client messages

Then you need

A data structure that supports tracking multiple simultaneous connections and the outbound data directed to each.
To broaden the scope of the server's main loop to include accept()ing new clients
A plan for accepting / reading / writing that avoids service to one client being delayed by the program blocking on service to a different client.

There are two main styles for approaching those:

Devote a separate thread or process to each client.  The main thread / process is then devoted to accepting new clients, and each time it does, it launches a thread or process to service that client.  The different client-service units will in this case require a communication mechanism by which to forward incoming messages to the other client-service units.  Each one will also have some some kind of queue for outbound messages, into which it can receive the messages from other clients.

Use non-blocking I/O and multiplex service to all the clients via select() / poll() or one of the other, similar facilities for the purpose.  This allows a single thread of a single process to serve multiple clients by skipping around among them according to which is ready for what action at any given time.  Network I/O has considerable latency, especially when there are humans in the loop, so a relatively large number of concurrent clients can be handled this way.


For your particular case, if you choose to use multithreading or multiprocessing then you may need to have two threads / processes for each client, or else to use multiplexing as well, because you want to avoid that blocking on reading from / writing to one client delays writing to / reading from that same client.
Either way, there is considerable bookkeeping to manage.  The data structures for that are probably a bit simpler with multithreading / multiprocessing, but that is offset by the need to manage synchronization and communication amongst all those service units.

To accept and handle multiple clients concurrently, you'll need to use the concept of multithreading, like POSIX thread library (pthreads).
Server
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define PORT 8080
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

// Function to handle client communication
void *handle_client(void *client_socket) {
    int sock = *(int *)client_socket;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int n;

    while ((n = recv(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, 0)) > 0) {
        buffer[n] = '\0'; // Null-terminate the received data
        printf("Client: %s\n", buffer);

        // Echo the received message back to the client
        send(sock, buffer, n, 0);
    }

    if (n == 0) {
        printf("Client disconnected\n");
    } else {
        perror("recv");
    }

    close(sock);
    free(client_socket);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main() {
    int server_fd, new_socket, *client_socket;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int addrlen = sizeof(address);
    pthread_t thread_id;

    // Creating socket file descriptor
    if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0) {
        perror("socket failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Setting up the address structure
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    // Binding the socket
    if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address)) < 0) {
        perror("bind failed");
        close(server_fd);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Listening for incoming connections
    if (listen(server_fd, 3) < 0) {
        perror("listen");
        close(server_fd);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Server is listening on port %d\n", PORT);

    while (1) {
        // Accepting new client connection
        if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, (socklen_t *)&addrlen)) < 0) {
            perror("accept");
            close(server_fd);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        // Allocating memory for client socket descriptor
        client_socket = malloc(sizeof(int));
        *client_socket = new_socket;

        // Creating a new thread to handle the client
        if (pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, handle_client, (void *)client_socket) < 0) {
            perror("pthread_create");
            close(new_socket);
            free(client_socket);
            continue;
        }

        // Detaching the thread so that it can clean up after itself
        pthread_detach(thread_id);
    }

    close(server_fd);
    return 0;
}

Client
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT 8080
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

int main() {
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    char *message = "Hello from client";

    // Creating socket
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("socket creation error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Setting up the server address structure
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    // Convert IPv4 and IPv6 addresses from text to binary form
    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &server_address.sin_addr) <= 0) {
        perror("Invalid address / Address not supported");
        close(sock);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Connecting to the server
    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server_address, sizeof(server_address)) < 0) {
        perror("Connection failed");
        close(sock);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Sending a message to the server
    send(sock, message, strlen(message), 0);
    printf("Message sent\n");

    // Receiving a response from the server
    int n = recv(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, 0);
    if (n > 0) {
        buffer[n] = '\0'; // Null-terminate the received data
        printf("Server: %s\n", buffer);
    } else {
        perror("recv");
    }

    close(sock);
    return 0;
}


Accepting multiple connections does not require multiple threads
